# Check whether list of string available in list of tuple with Python

Tags: python

The objective is to check whether look-up list of string available in a list of tuple.

Specifically, check whether any of these item in the `look-up` list `drop_cols`

```
drop_cols=['cond', 'main', 'sub', 'task']
```

available in the list of tuple `ndata`

```
ndata=[('main', '', ''),('task', '', ''),('sub', '', ''),
('cond', '', ''),('misc_mycom', 'ch', '300')]
```

This can be achieved as

```
all_test=[x == dval for dval in nval for x in drop_cols]
```

Then, to test the result

```
if sum(all_test)!=0:
    print ('item available')
```

However, I wonder whether there is more efficient way of doing this?

For completeness,
Within the `if-else`, there is the procedure:

```
for nval in ndata:
    # Check whether any item in the list of `drop_cols` available in the tuple of list of `ndata`
    all_test=[x == dval for dval in nval for x in drop_cols]
    if sum(all_test)!=0:
        b=nval  + ('',)
    else:
        b=nval  + (nval[0].split('_')[0] ,)
    all_vals.append(b)
```

or  in `list comprehension` form

```
all_vals= [nval + ('',) if sum ( [x == dval for dval in nval for x in drop_cols] ) != 0
      else nval + (nval [0].split ( '_' ) [0],) for nval in ndata]
```

Comment: If you only need a yes or no as the final result, you can chain `ndata` into a set and check for set difference with `drop_cols`.

Comment: Thanks @HenryYik, for completeness, I have add the `procedure` within the if-else statement. Btw, yes, as shown in the edit, expected output is only binary True False

Comment: What is your expected output from `all_vals`?

Comment: Please check the `list comprehension`, that should be the `all_vals` expected output

Comment: I think we can check just non existance and will break the loop. This is more performant way to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `set` difference instead:

```
drop_cols={'cond', 'main', 'sub', 'task'}

print ([i+("",) if set(i)&drop_cols else i+(i[0].split("_")[0],) for i in ndata])

[('main', '', '', ''), ('task', '', '', ''), ('sub', '', '', ''),
 ('cond', '', '', ''), ('misc_mycom', 'ch', '300', 'misc')]
```

Comment: This is better compare to the originally proposed

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to the accepted answer:

To maintain `drop_cols` as a type `list`

Compare as set for the `set(i) & set(drop_cols)`.

```
[i+("",) if set(i)&set(drop_cols) else i+(i[0].split("_")[0],) for i in ndata]
```